# Elaborate Steps for Openstack installation

Tags: cloud, openstack, failed-installation

I have already tried to install OpenStack on ubuntu 14.04 LTS lot of times ,but not able to. I found the steps to install OpenStack through Google search but it doesn't work. It crashes every time after 2 hours.

Please help me with elaborate steps to install OpenStack for ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Am not an expert on openstack but have done couple of test environments on ubuntu . I have just followed the official guides and haven't faced any issues. Can you pl. provide the following info so that we can try to help you better -

1. what type of architecture are you trying to install ?i.e All in one node or 2 node / 3 node architecture ?
2. When you say it crashes , what error message are you getting ? Is it the entire ubuntu VM crashing or only the openstack ?

If you can use other linux distros (CentOS, Fedora) then you can also try the RDO packstack.